# When can I use async.eachLimit instead of async.eachSeries

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I was reading a nodejs script the other day when I came across this line of code:

```
async.eachLimit(games, 1, handleSingleGame, callback)
```

My question is what is the difference between the previous call with the following:

```
async.eachSeries(games, handleSingleGame, callback)
```

I am really confused!!!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The only difference I see is that the first one does not insure the order of execution while the second executes in the same order. Am I right about this?

Comment: Because the limit is set to `1` so only one item can be processed at a time (e.g. 2nd can't be started until 1st is done) in the first option, I don't think there's any practical difference between these two.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you my friend, that's what I thought too but I'm new to nodejs so I had to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

Because the limit is set to `1` so only one item can be processed at a time (e.g. 2nd can't be started until 1st is done) in the first option, I don't think there's any practical difference between these two.